# Windows элемент для выбора из списка(поле раскрывающегося типа)

Tags: c#

Полистал книги, но не нашел. Как называется такой элемент? как с ним работать? где о нем можно почитать?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стандартный ListBox. Почитать можно в MSDN: [класс ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx). [Пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/95408c5t(v=VS.90).aspx) использования ListBox и ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

[Элементы управления "ListBox" и "ComboBox"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/khd0t3w0(v=vs.90).aspx)